# How to rotate the contents of 16x16 bitmap array using only maths (no scaling, just clip the corners off)

Tags: c++, bitmap, rotation

another question from me about bitmaps! A quick intro to this: I'm working on a university project where I have no external libraries, only the basic windows/c++, this bitmap rotation must be done entirely by simply modifying pixels in an array.

I have a 16x16 bitmap (it's just a COLORREF array that's 16x16 elements long) and I want to rotate it about the centre point (or any point actually).

I have some code that *almost* works, it rotates it about the top-left corner so I know I'm close, I just don't know what to edit to offset that by 8 pixels as everything I can think of results in overflowing out of the 16x16 area.

Here's the code I currently have (which I grabbed from DrDobbs and modified it a bit, it had a scaling parameter (the (1.0) parts) which I didn't need).

```
void Sprite::DrawAt(Render* render, int x, int y, double angle)
{
    COLORREF* tmp = new COLORREF[width * height];
    int u, v;

    for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<width; j++)
        {
            u = cos(-angle) * j * (1.0) + sin(-angle) * i * (1.0);
            v = -sin(-angle) * j * (1.0) + cos(-angle) * i * (1.0);
            tmp[(i * width) + j] = bitmap[(v * width) + u];
        }
    }

    // x-(width/2) renders it at the centre point instead of the top-left
    render->BlockShiftBitmap(tmp, x - (width/2), y - (height/2), width, height, -1);

    delete[] tmp;
}
```

(Excuse some of the bad coding habits here, I'm only interested in the topic at hand, everything else will get cleaned up another time).

That code results in this:

[http://puu.sh/hp4nB/8279cd83dd.gif http://puu.sh/hp4nB/8279cd83dd.gif](http://puu.sh/hp4nB/8279cd83dd.gif)

It rotates around the top-left corner, and it also grabs out of bounds memory too. I could do with a solution that rotates around the centre (or any point, that would come in handy later on for things such as doors!) and also clips off the corners and ensures no random bits of memory end up in the resulting bitmap.

The result should *hopefully* look something like this with the black pixels turned white:

[http://puu.sh/hp4uc/594dca91da.gif http://puu.sh/hp4uc/594dca91da.gif](http://puu.sh/hp4uc/594dca91da.gif)

(don't ask what the hell that creature is! he's some kind of red-eared debug-lizard)

Thanks, you awesome people here have helped quite a bit on this little project of mine!

Comment: In order to rotate around the center, subtract half the width/height before, and add after rotation. Also, you definitely should check the bounds of u and v before accessing your bitmap! Not doing so causes undefined behavior, here resulting in garbage pixels. When they are out of bounds, use white (or transparent, but you said you want white...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate around an origin (`ox`, `oy`), first substract these coordinates, then rotate, and then add them again.

```
// Choose the center as the origin
ox = width / 2;
oy = height / 2;

// Rotate around the origin by angle
u =  cos(-angle) * (j-ox) + sin(-angle) * (i-oy) + ox;
v = -sin(-angle) * (j-ox) + cos(-angle) * (i-oy) + oy;
```

Then, add a bounds check before accessing your image, and use a replacement color for the "background", in case the coordinates are not within the bounds:

```
 if (u >= 0 && u < width && v >= 0 && v < height)
     tmp[(i * width) + j] = bitmap[(v * width) + u];
 else
     tmp[(i * width) + j] = 0;   // However you represent white...
```

Comment: Works perfectly! It was the +ox/+oy that I was missing and the final check was the icing on the cake. Thank you! :) http://puu.sh/hp5jE/0669373fcd.gif

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with the rest of your project, it looks fun! :)

Answer (score 2):

could you try subtracting 8 from i's and j's

```
u = cos(-angle) * (j-8) * (1.0) + sin(-angle) * (i-8) * (1.0);
v = -sin(-angle) * (j-8) * (1.0) + cos(-angle) * (i-8) * (1.0);
```

Comment: @Southclaw See my comment below your question, it should fix that